# NextJS 404.js works only on development mode

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, next.js, custom-error-pages

NextJs (v.12) Page 404  (pages/404.js) works only on development mode > after deploying to amplify it doesn't work . When given incorrect url it redirect to home page ('/').

dont know whats happening please help

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Rewrites and redirects` in your Amplify console, and remove the entry:

```
/<*> /index.html 404 (Rewrite)
```